# Java For Loop or While Loop For the Task

Tags: java

Inside a Box can fit 5 Books.

Shipping the first 5 Boxes cost 5 Dollars /Box.

Shipping more than five Boxes cost 4 Dollars /Box.

If the user types in 30 Books.

It will 29 Dollars (5* 5 Dollar / Box ) + ( 4 Dollar / Box)

Now if I want to make Java calculate the cost of shipping, I ran into problems.

First, I don't know if I should use For loops or while loops.

I first did this:

```
int Box = books_count_X / 5
int VolumeofFive$BOX = 0
int VolumeofFour$BOX = 0 ;


for (Box ; VolumeofFive$BOX < 6 ; ) {
                    VolumeofFive$BOX = i++;

                }
```

I'm not even sure if that's how you do it, and it doesn't work to my surprise.

I don't know how to write that in code : for each Box, increase `VolumeofFive$BOX` by 1, as long as `VolumeofFive$BOX` didn't reach 6.

How do you write it in code?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of what would give you the right result. 30 books would result in 29 Dollars.

```
int Box = (books_count_X + 4) / 5;
int VolumeofFive$BOX = 0;
int VolumeofFour$BOX = 0 ;

for ( int i = 1; i <= Box; i++ ) {
    if ( i <= 5 ) {
        VolumeofFive$BOX++; // increment the amount of boxes
    } else {
        VolumeofFour$BOX++; // increment the other amount of boxes
    }
}

// total for first 5 boxes:
int totalA = VolumeofFive$BOX * 5;
// total for all the remaining boxes:
int totalB = VolumeofFour$BOX * 4;
// total amount
int total = totalA + totalB;
```

Comment: I don't want to edit your answer, but the first line should read *int Box = (books_count_X + 4) / 5;*  Try your code with one book.  Java variable names should start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: Thanks (j'avais complètement raté la possibilité d'en avoir moins que 5). I've edited the answer.